# Can I modify the property of an Autowired Singleton scoped bean and have that value for the entire application?

Tags: java, spring

I think I know the answer but would like to confirm:

So I have a singleton bean initialized and two class that uses it:
I set the property of the bean in Class A

```
public class A {
   @Autowired
   MyBean exampleBean

   public void modifyBean() {
      exampleBean.setValue() = 5;

}
```

Later on in Class B, the value is retrieved...

```
public class B {
   @Autowired
   MyBean exampleBean

   public void modifyBean() {
      int value = exampleBean.getValue();
}
```

Would value = 5 then?

Comment: how are you getting value 5 and from where? I can tell later how to modify singleton.

Comment: @silentsudo he is modifying the singleton by calling a setter and passing a value. The 5 is hardcoded. Read both classes

Comment: @Stultuske you are not being helpful here, the value 5 is hardcode I can see, I wanted to know under what circumstances it is happening if is just a hardcoded value we can pick up from application.properties or env keeping the integrity of singleton class. Usually, configuration of beans can be picked from properties files.

Comment: @silentsudo please try and understand the question. He is asking "if I set this value in class A, will it also be set for class B". You are thinking about things that are not related to the question. The answer is "yes, since it's a Singleton", it's that simple